# Error during template rendering in Django framework

Tags: python, django, error-handling

Error during template rendering,
I used for loop to iterate categories in home page,home page isn't loading after I put this code:

```
<a href="{% url 'ProductPage' catg=d.CategoryName %}">
```

home page :

```
<div class="row">
   <!-- single product -->

                {% for d in data %}
   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
      <div class="single-product">
         <img class="img-fluid" src="{{d.CategoryImage.url}}" alt="">
         <div class="product-details">
            <a href="{% url 'ProductPage' catg=d.CategoryName %}">
            <h6>{{d.CategoryName}}</h6>
            </a>
            <div class="price">
               <h6>$150.00</h6>
               <h6 class="l-through">$210.00</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="prd-bottom">

               <a href="" class="social-info">
                  <span class="ti-bag"></span>
                  <p class="hover-text">add to bag</p>
               </a>
               <a href="" class="social-info">
                  <span class="lnr lnr-heart"></span>
                  <p class="hover-text">Wishlist</p>
               </a>
               <a href="" class="social-info">
                  <span class="lnr lnr-sync"></span>
                  <p class="hover-text">compare</p>
               </a>
               <a href="" class="social-info">
                  <span class="lnr lnr-move"></span>
                  <p class="hover-text">view more</p>
               </a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   {% endfor %}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from MyApp.models import CategoryDB, ProductDB

# Create your views here.
def homepage(request):
    data = CategoryDB.objects.all()
    return render(request,"home.html",{'data':data})
def aboutpage(request):
    return render(request,"about.html")
def ProductPage(request,catg):
    prod = ProductDB.objects.filter(Category_Name=catg)
    return render(request,"products.html", {'prod':prod})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from webapp import views

urlpatterns=[
    path('homepage/',views.homepage, name="homepage"),
    path('aboutpage/', views.aboutpage, name="aboutpage"),
    path('ProductPage/<catg>/', views.ProductPage, name="ProductPage"),
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class CategoryDB(models.Model):
    CategoryName = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank= True)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank= True)
    CategoryImage = models.ImageField(upload_to="CategoryImages", null=True, blank=True)

class ProductDB(models.Model):
    Category_Name= models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    Product_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    Quantity = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    Price= models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    Product_Image = models.ImageField(upload_to="ProductImages",null=True,blank=True)
```

Comment: Can you share the error traceback?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `<str:catg>` in you'r url instead of just `<catg>`